# How to introduce attribute to method of class and use it?

Tags: python-3.x

For my application, I would like to realize a simple game of Word-Guess where
the computer choices a word from the dictionary and player try to guess it.

I have a method typing() use to check if each letter it is at the right place according to the word to guess and put it in a list at it index if yes.

I would like now to get another variable that can store a letter which are in the word to guess but at the wrong index; but after the execution this variable is still empty.

My code is:

```py
***list_class.py*** 

    from random import  choice
    from donnees import *
    from fonctions import fichier_score

    class Word_Guess(object):

    """This class is use to manage all actions about word guess by the user """
    def __init__(self, word_to_find):
        self.letter = choice(word_to_find[1:])
        self.essai_en_cours = ["*" for i in word_to_find]
        idx = word_to_find.index(self.letter)
        self.essai_en_cours[idx] = self.letter
        self.essai_en_cours[0] = word_to_find[0]
        print('le mot à deviner est :')
        for i in self.essai_en_cours:
            print(i, end='   ')
        print('')
        


    def typing(self, word_to_find):
        """function use to take a word typing by user """
        self.word = input('Entrer votre mot: ').strip()
        self.help_letter = list()

        if "".join(self.word).isalpha() and len(self.word) == len(word_to_find):
            for indice, lettre in enumerate(self.word):
                if word_to_find[indice] == lettre:
                    self.essai_en_cours[indice] = lettre
                if lettre in word_to_find and word_to_find[indice] != lettre:
                    self.help_letter.append(lettre)

            print(self.help_letter)

        else:
            print(" le mot entre comporte un carcactere non alphabétique \
                ou n'a pas la longueur requise!")


**main.py**

    from fonctions import *
    from list_classs import *

    word_to_fin = word_to_find()
        print(word_to_fin)
        game = Word_Guess(word_to_fin)
        suite = True
        essai_restants = essais
        while suite and essai_restants:
            essai_restants -= 1
            game.typing(word_to_fin)

**donnees.py**

    essais = 4
    suite = True
    continuer = True
    
    dictionary = ['CALORISA', 'IMPÉTIGO', 'GUDARDES', 'FERNWALD', 'DÉGUILLE', 'BACHOTES', 'NÉONEREZ', 'DARTRIER',
    'TARZOLLÉ', 'RÉCITAIS', 'CÉSURERA', 'PERRIÈRE', 'ÉQUIGNON', 'JINGZHOU', 'KEULKEUL', 'JERRICAN', 'HUMÈRENT',
    'VOTERAIT', 'GLOSSÈME', 'REFORUME', 'PERDANTS', 'REMENÉES', 'JOGGEREZ', 'BARIAUDS', 'GAUGEONS', 'DÉTISAIT',
    'MÉGILIEN', 'BOÉSIENS', 'BARULAIS', 'CAUSASSE', 'RECAMENT', 'BALENÇÂT', 'GUILLANT', 'RÉVEILLE', 'SURSEMÉS',
    'HERRENAS', 'COUCHEUR', 'CHINÂTES', 'RECÉDERA', 'ORPIMENT', 'TARTRAGE', 'RIVEMENT', 'PINGUIEZ', 'ROBELAGE', 'CHRYSIDE', 'ALUNAGES', 'AIGUILLE', 'MINORAIS', 'MAUBELAN', 'ÉMENDAIT'] 

**fonctions.py**

    from unicodedata import normalize
    from random import choice
    from donnees import *
    
    def word_to_find():
        word_to_find = choice(dictionary).upper()
    # conversion de la chaine en majuscule non accentuée
        return  normalize("NFD", word_to_find).encode('ascii', 'ignore'\
            ).decode('ascii')
```

Comment: I will have a look at it tomorrow. I think the game is called 'Lingo' here. Thus far I'm suspecting the condition `if lettre in word_to_find and word_to_find[indice] != lettre:` but it might be a combination with something else as well.

Comment: @GabinTEKAM, thanks for adding all your code, but could you make sure the formatting (especially indenting) is correct? It currently is not. The easiest way is to put a line with three backticks and the used language (in this case `\`\`\`python`) before your code, and put a line with three backticks (`\`\`\``) behind it. Then you don't have to change the indenting of your code, you can just copy-paste it without errors. See [Markdown Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to the fact that the word typed by player did not have the same case with word guessed by computer.
For this reason, I have converted the word typed by player into **uppercase**

old code was:

```py
    def typing(self, word_to_find):
        """function use to take a word typing by user """
        self.word = input('Entrer votre mot: ').strip()
        ...
```

and it was modify to:

```py
    def typing(self, word_to_find):
        """function use to take a word typing by user """
        self.word = input('Entrer votre mot: ').upper().strip()
        ...
```